# How to configure SMTP to recognize a group

Tags: windows-server-2008, java, smtp

I'm using a windows server. I installed **IIS SMPT server** and using it. I have no problem when I send a mail to individual id. But I get an error when trying to send to a group.

```
    InternetAddress m_fromAddress = new InternetAddress("me@sample.com");
    InternetAddress m_toAddress = new InternetAddress("group@sample.com");
```

**Error :**

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification. Delivery to the following recipients failed. group@sample.com

What configuration changes do I need to make in my SMPT server for a group.

Comment: The recipient system is responsible for group expansion. So by principle it would depend on what you have configured your iis to do with mail you generate and pass to it. Are you collecting mail there or forwarding it to another mail system? Could you tell us more?

Comment: Does the group actually exist? Does the email address for the group exist?

Comment: Yes, the group I have in code is available. I can send mail from my outlook to this group.